# Combining PCA, feature scaling, and cross-validation without training-test data leakage

Tags: machine-learning, pca, cross-validation, scikit-learn, data-leakage

The [sci-kit learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) for cross-validation says the following about using feature-scaling and cross-validation:

> Just as it is important to test a predictor on data held-out from training, preprocessing (such as standardization, feature selection, etc.) and similar data transformations similarly should be learnt from a training set and applied to held-out data for prediction

I understand the reason behind this is to prevent information leakage between the training & test sets during cross-validation, which could result in an optimistic estimate of model performance.

I am wondering then, if I wish to use Principal Component Analysis to reduce the size of a feature set before training say a regression model, and PCA requires feature-scaling to be effective, how do I chain feature-scaling to PCA to cross-validated regression, without introducing data leakage between the train-test splits in the cross-validation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to think feature scaling, then pca, then your regression model as an unbreakable chain of operations (as if it is a single model), in which the cross validation is applied upon. This is quite tricky to code it yourself but considerably easy in `sklearn` via [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)s. A pipeline object is a cascade of operators on the data that is regarded (and acts) as a seemingly single model confirming to `fit` and `predict` paradigm in the library.

Comment: Thank you - I just discovered `Pipeline` myself while researching this issue, and have come up with a solution that seems to work - will post my code in case it's useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 12):

For the benefit of possible readers who don't use the scikit pipeline:

- Centering and scaling the *training* subset does not only result in the centered and scaled training data but also in vectors describing the offset and scaling factor.  When predicting new cases, *this* offset and scale is applied to the new case, and the resulting centered and scaled data then passed to the principal component prediction
- which in turn applies the rotation determined from fitting the training data.
- and so on, until the final prediction is reached.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who might stumble upon this question, I have a solution using scikit-learn's [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline), as recommended in the accepted answer. Below is the code I used to get this to work for my problem, chaining together `StandardScaler`, `PCA` and `Ridge` regression into a cross-validated grid-search:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe = Pipeline([("scale", StandardScaler()),
                 ("reduce_dims", PCA()),
                 ("ridge", Ridge())
                ])


param_grid = dict(reduce_dims__n_components = [0.5, 0.75, 0.95],
                  ridge__alpha = np.logspace(-5, 5, 10),
                  ridge__fit_intercept = [True, False],
                 )

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've encounter some problems with pipelines (for example, if I want to apply my own custom function, it is a real hazard) so here is what I use instead:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, stratify=Y, random_state=seed, test_size=0.2)
sc = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
pca = PCA().fit(X_train)
X_train = pca.transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
eclf = SVC()
parameters_grid = {
                'C': (0.1, 1, 10)
                   }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(eclf, parameters_grid, cv=cv, refit='auc', return_train_score=True)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_model = eclf.set_params(**grid_search.best_params_).fit(X_train, y_train)
test_auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, best_model.predict(X_test))
```

I realize it is a bit long but it is clear on what you are doing.